# Print Screen Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to create ID Card for college, and i created it as i wanted in html(modal), but while i press print button, it just print the background and no content is displayed on it.
ID Card On Modal :

[image]
ID Card On Print Page :

[image]

Code :

```
  <style>
            @media print
            {    
                div {
                    content:url(dist/img/bahtiid.png);
                    width: 323.527559055px;
                    height: 204.018897638px;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
                .img {
                    content:url(dist/img/user2.jpg);
                    width: 90px;
                    height: 100px;
                }
                .no-print, .no-print *
                {
                    display: none !important;
                }
                .print, .print *
                {
                    display: block;
                }
            }
            @page {
                size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
                margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
            }
        </style>
     <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header no-print">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body print">


                    <div style="width:323.527559055px; height:204.018897638px; border: 1px solid black; background-image: url(dist/img/bahtiid.png);background-size: 323.527559055px 204.018897638px; z-index:-1;">
                    <div class="col-md-12 print">

                        <br /><br /><br />
                        <div class="col-md-9 print" style="font-size:12px; margin-left:-10px">
                            <b> Name : </b> Swapnil J Khadke <br />
                            <b> Address : </b> 29, sadguru nagar, MIDC Area, Jalgaon. <br />
                            <b> Class : </b> ENGG 
                            <b> Year : </b> 2016-17 <br />
                            <b> DOB : </b> 16-11-2016 
                            <b> Blood Group : </b> O+ <br />
                            <b> Email : </b> swap.wk@gmail.com <br />
                            <b> Mobile : </b> 9999999999 <br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" ><img class="img" src="dist/img/user2.jpg" style="width:90px; height:100px; margin-left: -40px; margin-top: -2px;"></div>
                    </div>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer no-print">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()" >Print</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or so...

Comment: I've tried to build a fiddle out of this, but it seems quite hard to test the print functionality via codepen... I deleted my last answer as it wasn't applicable to your problem. However, can I ask what the div with z-index: -1 is meant to be doing? Because that is likely to drop things behind the background...

Comment: @AaronLavers : actually i was trying to take that background to back of the text so that text can be visible to front, but it dint worked.

Comment: I just fiddled around with the basic fiddle I made here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaMWWb    Your .div style is setting it's background image, which is completely covering everything else. It's also applying that to every div in there. You should instead set the background image with `background: url(...) no-repeat`  instead of the content attribute

Comment: Also, you should name the main container with a class, and target that with the CSS instead of just targeting .div

Answer (score 0):

When the @print styles are invoked, your .div class is setting all it's content to the image (using the content: attribute). Instead, you should set your background image using

```
background: url(......) no-repeat top center;
```

Then, you should name the main card div, and target that instead of just targeting .div. Because the way your style is now, it will set the background image, size, and border for every div in the DOM.

Comment: Weird, even though your answer is 35min older, I didn't see it and posted a similar one. Deleted it again as your answer already correctly identifies the problem.

Comment: @Aaron Lavers : when i change content to background its not working, but the text is displayed and that too not in proper format. and also i added class to that div instead of targeting all div.

Comment: @Paul  yeah I'd deleted it, then edited and undeleted it haha. Sorry!

Comment: @swap you'll probably need to build more css to control the layout of the text inside the box - if you name the col-md-9 print div with another class (like .text or something) you can then apply styles to that div to control your text layout. I did noticed all the text looked weird when I was playing with the fiddle.